# Redirect logged in users from a specific page to Woocommerce my account page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I am trying to find a solution for checking if a user is logged in on custom page and if so, redirect user to "My Account" page.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, where you will replace **`'some-page'`** by your real page ID, slug or name. The code will redirect for a defined specific page logged in users to the my account page:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'specific_logged_in_redirect');
function specific_logged_in_redirect() {
    if ( is_page('some-page') && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

For 2 pages you will use: `is_page( array( 'some-page', 'some-other' ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You should use an $_SESSION.
This help you to validate if the user log on in the page.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['UserID'])){
    header('Location: [url]');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Wordpress :

```
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 0 != $current_user->ID ) {
        $template = get_page_template_slug($post->ID);
        if($template == "your_custom_template_name"){
             wp_redirect( wp_login_url() )    
        }   
    }
```